# YII: Dropdownlist with relation

Tags: yii, relational-database, inner-join

> DB table:
>
> - Mcourse(Master course )-> contains Course Names
> - Lcourse(Linked
>   Course- courses belongs to a college) -> contains foreign key
>   Mcourse_Id. & college Id.

Nw the problem is

> I want to display list of courses available in a college using dropdownlist.

So sql query is:

> select Lcourse_Id, Mcourse_Name* from Lcourse inner join Mcourse on Lcourse_Mcourse_Id=Mcourse Id..

```
*Id & value pair for dropdownlist
```

I could do this usin createCommand..Its working pretty fine. But i cant do this usin Relations ..Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's imagine for a minute that your `Mcourse` table is called `courses` and model for that table is called `Courses`, your `Lcourse` table is called `courses_colleges` and your colleges table is `colleges` and model for that table is `Colleges`

Now, You should have `Courses` model with relations:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'colleges' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Colleges', 'courses_colleges(course_id, college_id)')
    );
}
```

Your `Colleges` model should have similar relations:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'courses' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Courses', 'courses_colleges(college_id, course_id)')
    );
}
```

Now if you want to print out a dropdown with all courses available for a certain college. In your controller action method get the model of that college including its courses:

```
public function actionShow() {
    $id = 1; // We set just some sample id. You could get it from request ofc.
    $college = Colleges::model()->with('courses')->findByPk($id);
    $this->render('show', array('college'=>$college));
}
```

Now in your view print out this:

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('courses', '', CHtml::listData($college->courses, 'id', 'name'));
```

Where `'id'` and `'name'` are columns of your `Courses` model.

Something like that.

Comment: You cannot set college_id through default scope, because in that case college_id will be constant and you will be able to use this models just for 1 college. And relations describe how models are linked to each other. If you have the link then you should declare it anyways.

Comment: Every User has a college_Id.So ill be storing College_Id in session (yii:app->User->CollegeId) once they login. & in most of the controller i hv set default scope as collegeId. So what is the need of putting $id=yii::app()->User->CollegeId ??
Default scope:
'condition'=>"collge_Id='".Yii::app()->User->CollegeId."'",

Comment: Don't use Default scope. That's just an advice. If you want to use scope there, you can create new scope method in model, for example `default_college` and then when you search for model: `Courses::model()->default_college()->findAll();` It is important to know that you cannot dynamically remove default scope. For example, if in the future user wants to see what courses are in ANOTHER college, he won't be able to do that. And you won't be able to program that. Default scope is very very bad thing to use.

Comment: Do u hv any blog..So that i can follow u?

Comment: No, sorry, i don't have a blog. But you can find tons of good stuff by following in twitter this guy: @tonydspaniard every day he posts lots of links and interesting articles related to Yii.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the listData() function in your view, specifically that you don't have a mc_Id in your Lcourse model.

As you haven't clarified the model that each of those relationships are assigned with, it's impossible to guess what you should substitute for 'mc_Id' in your view - check your Lcourse model to determine the proper column name.

Comment: Thanks fr the quick reply.
mc_Id is in Mcourse model..i want to inner join Mcourse & Lcourse & hv to get Mcourse.mcId & Lcourse.lcors_Id(FK) ..hw should i??

Comment: The query is something like this
select l.lcors_Id, m.mc_Id from Lcourse as `l` inner join Mcourse as `m` on l.locrs_mc_Id=m.mc_Id.
Hw sud i implement dis in dropdownlist.